# How to maintain the V8 contexts for future use?

Tags: c++, v8

I need to execute Javascript using V8 in my C code. My C application access web server links and gets html data, images and javascript. For example, I have got 2 javascripts say js1.js and js2.js as shown below.

### js1.js

```
function js_add_elements(var1, var2) 
{ 
    var var3 = parseInt(var1) + parseInt(var2); 
    var result = 'Addition of ' + var1 + ' and ' + var2 + ' results ' + var3; 
    return result; 
}
```

### js2.js

```
js_add_elements(2, 3);
```

Typically we need few objects to run javascript in V8. I have kept some contexts in global datastructure, I call it instance.

```
Instance level contexts    
std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform;
v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
v8::Isolate *isolate;
v8::Isolate::Scope *isolate_scope;
```

and also I have kept some contexts as local members in a function as below.

```
Local contexts in a function
v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
v8::Local<v8::Context> context;
v8::Context::Scope context_scope;
v8::Local<v8::String> source;
v8::Local<v8::Script> script;
```

Keeping the contexts as above, I can run js1.js and js2.js and get desired result. Say after sometime I get js3.js from server and file looks as below.

### js3.js

```
js_add_elements(5, 6); 
js_add_elements(7, 8);
```

Now the problem starts. I will go and try to execute js3.js. By this time the contexts declared in local function are deleted (by garbage collector). When I try to execute js3.js, the contexts will be allocated newly and it would not have js1.js so it results **undefined**.

I hope there should be some way out to keep contexts alive for certain period. I am just not getting it.

Can somebody please help to learn how to keep context alive till certain time (say for lifetime of a session).

Answer (score 1):

Adjacent to where you're storing your `v8::Isolate`, you should be able to just store the context in a `v8::Global` (so a `v8::Global<v8::Context>`).

See the following Chromium code for an example.

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/renderer/script_context.h?l=254&rcl=6f4a318b668d531303276b6bac424ab4bce9911b

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/renderer/script_context.cc?l=109&rcl=6f4a318b668d531303276b6bac424ab4bce9911b

Comment: Thanks. If I understand I will declare v8::Global<v8::Context> where I have declared v8::Isolate. Do I need to set anything to v8::Global<v8::Context> member. It will be helpful if you can put an example preferably in C.

Comment: I searched a lot. Not getting exact reference. I create v8 Local context. Probably I need to somehow set it to global context. Not getting how to do it. Is it possible for you to add a small example code in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: What aspect of the Chromium code isn't clear to you?  The first link is them declaring the `v8::Global<v8::Context>`, and the second link is them initializing it.  Creating the `v8::Global` from the `v8::Local` should be as simple as invoking the `v8::Global::Global(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<S>)` (where `S`=`v8::Context`) constructor (https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/include/v8.h?l=733-742&rcl=45ddaacef4d3cd90c58d766380fc1f418f998cd2).

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure it out.